# What is difference between "topology of network" and "geometry of network"?

Tags: design, networking, terminology, topology

In the Internet some times, we hear of the term **"geometry of the network"**:
https://bit.ly/2VqI2YO

Is there any difference between the term of **"geometry of the network"** and **"topology of the network"**?

In other words, when I see the term of **"geometry of the network"** in the above links, we must consider this term as **"topology of the network"**? Or it means differently?

Comment: Most of the time "network geometry" doesn't make too much sense. You build networks as a bus, in stars, trees, rings but these are topologies. Above the actual topology you might use "architecture" for a more abstract scope.

Comment: @Zac67 you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I suppose things like a spanning tree _diameter_ could be referred to as the _geometry_.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was thinking along the same lines ("bisection bandwidth", ...) but I wouldn't call that "geometry".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Converted from comment*

Most of the time, "network geometry" doesn't make too much sense. You build networks as a bus, in stars, trees, rings but these are topologies. Above the actual topology you might use "architecture" for a more abstract scope.

The links you've given provide *very* abstract views on networking concepts. I'm not at all sure in how far they are of practical use.

While there are somewhat *geometric* views in networking including "network diameter", "tree depth", "bisection bandwidth", these views help you handle the complexity of a larger network better, identify potential bottlenecks or breaking points before they happen.

However, when designing a network you don't start with geometric considerations. You start with a proven, best practice topology and adapt that to your current needs.

Comment: Not disagreeing with a word of this, just adding that if I heard "network geometry" I'd expect a statement like "there are 3 sites, each with about 200 desk-bound worker hosts, about 100 km apart, and site 3 also has 50 servers, and site 3 is a long thin warehouse 500 metres long."  These measurements drive us to topologies.

Comment: @jonathanjo Another possibility. I'm not sure if the OP refers to that though - if he has something specific in his mind.